# Order of evaluation when using a parameter and this keyword

Tags: c++

What is the order of evaluation when using the keyword `this` and a parameter in a function described below:

```
bool isObject(MyClass& a)
    {
        if (&a==this) return true;
        else return false;
    }
```

Is it equivalent to

```
if (this==&a)
```

which would make the `==` operator commutative for pointers?
This snippet was taken from a [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/) tutorial.

Comment: If you're asking whether `operator==` is commutative for pointers, then yes, it is.

Comment: Hm, right you are chris. I will rephrase my question. I suggest you turn that comment into an answer.

Comment: This should help out, change the two lines to `return (&a == this);`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Very nice. What's the best practice when comparing the two in terms of which one comes first? Or is it a matter of style?

Comment: You're making a copy of the argument to `isObject()`, how will this function ever return `true`?

Comment: It's a matter of style and readability.  To the language, it doesn't matter, as they are *commutative*.  Some people prefer to put constants first because it helps detect `=` from `==` mistakes.  Research "yoda coding".

Comment: The method from code provided accepts parameter by value. That will always return false unless you accept it by reference.

bool MyClass::isThisObject(MyClass& a)
{
   return &a==this;
}

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Very nice. I suggest you turn that into an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @Praetorian, I'm kind of ashamed of this, but http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6054149066f35098 (simplified slightly)

Comment: @chris Should've known someone would come up with a way to do it. Shame on you :P

Comment: The question as to whether == is commutative has nothing to do with order of evaluation. What are you really asking here?

Comment: I am asking both questions. In relation to using the above operands.

Comment: Why would order of evaluation concern you? Neither operand is an expression or has side-effects. I believe C++ defines order of evaluation as 'as-if left to right' (open to correction), but it doesn't make any difference here.

Comment: @EJP, The order is unspecified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `==` operator is indeed always commutative, unless you have overloaded it. So (unless overloaded) you can safely change

```
if (&a==this) return true;
else return false;
```

to

```
return this == &a
```

or

```
return &a == this
```

Comment: The fact that it is commutative has nothing to do with objects or pointers or references. It is a property of the operator and nothing else. If there was an override, what you say might make sense.

Comment: I've edited the post, but I was implying there could be an overload somewhere in the code, since not all is provided.